# Find the largest positive integer $k$ such that $S_5 \times S_5$ has an element of order $k$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find the largest positive integer $k$ such that $S_5 \times S_5$ has an element of order $k$.

I know by Lagrange that the order of any element of $S_5\times S_5$ divides $\left\lvert S_5\times S_5\right\rvert$. I assume that this is the way into the question but I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Start with [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231878/the-maximum-possible-order-for-an-element-s-n).

Comment: @DietrichBurde So is it 30?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

For an element $(a, b) \in S_5 \times S_5$, the order of that element is the LCM of the order of $a$ and the order of $b$. You know that the order of $a$ and the order of $b$ both have to divide the order of $S_5$, which is $120$ (but there are other limits, too, so [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/231893/307483) might help you find the different orders of elements in $S_5$). How can you maximize the LCM of their orders?

Comment: So is the answer 30?

Comment: @Si.0788 Yes, I'm pretty sure that's correct. Good job!