# What's the smallest exponent to give the identity in $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> Let $S_n$ denote the symmetric group on $n$ letters. We know that $\tau^{n!} = e$ for any element $\tau \in S_n,$ where $e$ denotes the identity element. Can we find a smaller positive integer $m$ with this property? That is, can we find a positive integer $m < n!$ such that $$\tau^m = e$$ for all $\tau \in S_n$?

Comment: Let $\sigma$ be an $n$-cycle. Then $\sigma^m\neq 1$ if $m<n$ since $\sigma$ has order $n$.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. For example $(1, 2)^3=(1, 2)\neq e$ in $S_3$. The order of the group $S_n$ is $n!$

Comment: I think I should have written $\tau^{n!} = e$. So is there a positive integer $m$ smaller than $n!$ such that $\tau^m=e$ for each element $\tau \in S_n$?

Comment: I would suggest to change the title to something like *What is the exponent of $S_{n}$?* See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_group

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A003418 for some interesting facts about these exponents. Note that the title of the sequence in the OEIS corresponds to Jyrki Lahtonen's answer and the first comment corresponds to mine.

Answer (score 8):

Hint (do all the steps): The order of a $k$-cycle is $k$. Any element of $S_n$ is a disjoint (hence commuting) product of cycles of length $\le n$. The order of a product of disjoint cycles is the l.c.m. of the lengths of the individual cycles.
The smallest exponent that works with all the permutations in $S_n$ is
$$
l.c.m.\{k\mid 1<k\le n\}.
$$

Comment: I was surprised that I didn't find this question already answered here. The closest related question may be [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/221211/11619).

Answer (score 6):

The answer is yes for $n \ge 4$. When you write a permutation $\tau$ as a product of disjoint cycles, its period $p$ is the lcm of the lengths of the cycles. So if $2^k$ divides $p$, $\tau$ contains a $2^k$ cycle and so $2^k \le n$. For $n \ge 4$, $n! = 2^rs$ where $s$ is odd and $2^r > n$, so $p$ will divide $m = 2^ks$, where $k$ is the largest integer such that $2^k \le n$. Similarly you can reduce the exponents of other prime divisors of $n!$ as soon as $n$ is large enough

Answer (score 1):

You do not need actually the symmetric group to do such a statement (though you should here correct the $n$ to $n!$).

Consider G a nontrivial group of order $n$.

Now either this group is cyclic (it has an element of order $n$) or it is not. If it is not the answer to your question is trivially yes: there is at least one element with order $m \neq n$. 
Now suppose it is a cyclic group, then $\langle g \rangle=G$. Now let us consider the case of n non prime and let us say that $m$ divedes $n$: $mk=n \Leftrightarrow g^{mk}=e \Leftrightarrow (g^{m})^{k} = e$

This proves that $g^m$ has order $k < m$.