Prove that if, for some $n$, $S_n$ has an element of order $16$, then it also has an element of order $70$.
This is an exam question I found. and was the last part on a question about finding the orders of permutation cycles.
So I'm thinking this is to do with the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups so element $|\sigma_1|$=16 has factorisation $2^4$ 70 has the factorisation $2\times5\times7$ as these are cyclic elements they are indeed abelian. But i don't know why $2^4$ would imply ther is an element $2\times5\times7=70$.

This is likely to be a duplicate question though . . .

$70=2\times5\times7$

yeah I got the $70=2\times 5 \times 7$ thanks , but why would that imply an element of 16 would relate to this?

How large is $n$ if $S_n$ has an element of order $16$, and what could an element of order $70$ look like?

After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: How do I accept an answer?, Why should we accept answers?, What should I do if someone answers my question?.

Not really a duplicate, but I was not able to find better: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493259 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576417

The divisors of $16$ are powers of two, so each of their $\operatorname{lcm}$s would be less than $16$ (e.g., $\operatorname{lcm}(2,8)=8$) unless you have just $16$. So the element $\sigma$ of order $16$ contains at least one cycle of length $16$. Thus $n\ge 16$. But $70=2\times 5\times 7$ and $2+5+7=14<16$, so all you need is an element of cycle type $(2,5,7)$, which has order $70$.

The element of order $16$ could have more than one cycle of length $16$ (if $n\ge32$)

Well spotted, @J.W.Tanner! Thank you! I have made a correction :)

But the main thing is there is no cycle lower than 16 and you can carry on with shaun's proof.

Thanks alot Shaun and  J. W. Tanner :)

You're welcome, @RichC.

So is it true an element of order 2^k can have no cycle lower than 2^k which is a handy thing to know.

@RichC This is false. For instance $(1234)(56)$ is of order $4$ and has a $2$-cycle. Shaun's answer only uses the fact that an element of order $2^k$ has at least one $2^k$-cycle.

Ok I see thanks alot

Please don't forget to accept this/an answer, @RichC.

ok done thanks again
