# Is there a good way to show that the order of element in $S_7$ are at most $12$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

The only solution would be going through all cycle types of all permutations which is a lot of work. Is there any smarter solution than this one?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/221211/11619). Anyway [Landau's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function) is what you want. Not voting to close, in case there are **smart tricks** for settling this specific case.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh, I see what you mean. What the OP thought was "a lot of work" was what I thought was already very economical.

Comment: Please check out this entry: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221211/maximal-order-of-an-element-in-a-symmetric-group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum order of an element of $S_n$ is assumed for a permutation which is a product of cycles of distinct lengths. So in stead of considering *all* cycle types, you only need to consider the cycle types
$$(1,2,4),\qquad (1,6),\qquad(2,5),\qquad(3,4),\qquad(7),$$
which quickly shows that the maximum order is $12$.

In fact more is true; the maximum is assumed for a cycle type of which the entries are pairwise coprime prime powers, where $1$ also counts as a prime power. This leaves only the latter three cycle types above, and for larger symmetric groups this reduces the number of cycle types to check significantly. This is harder to prove though.

**Edit:** To clarify, the sequences above are not cycles in $S_7$, but cycle *types* of elements of $S_7$. For example, the cycle type of $(2\ 3)(4\ 5\ 6\ 7)\in S_7$ is $(1,2,4)$, because it is the product of a $1$-cycle, a $2$-cycle and a $4$-cycle.

Comment: Triviality: you need to  consider $(7)$ as well.

Comment: @Servaes: Could you please explain me why I do not have to consider, for instance, the cycle type $(2,2,3)$? How can I deduce this case from you cases?

Comment: @ancientmathematician You are very right.

Comment: @Diglett If two cycles have the same length, you can replace them by one cycle of twice the length, and the order will not decrease. In your example $\operatorname{lcm}\{2,2,3\}\leq\operatorname{lcm}\{4,3\}$.

Comment: What does "type" mean here?  3 and 1 cycles I get... but why are there three random 2-cycles? I think i'm probably just missing something simple, but what eliminates 4-5-6-7 cycles at the start (besides inspection?)

Comment: @rschwieb I'm used to the terms of cycles being written without comma's, separated only by spaces. So for example $(1\ 2)$ and $(3\ 4\ 7)$ are cycles in $S_7$. A cycle *type* of an element of $S_7$ is a sequence $(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ of positive integers with $\sum c_i=7$. So the cycle type of $(1\ 2)(3\ 4\ 7)$ is $(3,2,1,1)$. I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: @Servaes OH, yeah I thought you were talking about cycle notation. That was my problem