# partition that maximizes lcm

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, integer-partitions

Let $n$ be a natural number. How can I find a partition of $n$ such that its least common multiple is maximized?

In other words, how can I find $a_1, a_2, \cdots a_m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_m = n \\\text{and} \\ \text{lcm}(a_1, a_2, \cdots ,a_m) \text{ is largest}$$
?

If not possible to find it, is the largest lcm value bounded by some functions of n? I tried to find it's upper bound by multiplying all numbers from each partition, and using a little calculus, able to drive the upper bound $e^{n/e}$. But it seems a bit too loose. Is there a better bound for lcm?

Comment: are all parts to be unique ?

Comment: This seems to be equivalent to finding the maximum order of any element in the symmetric group $S_n$.  So this may be helpful.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221211/maximal-order-of-an-element-in-a-symmetric-group

Comment: Wow, thanks @paw88789. Your answer was what I was looking for.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee what do you mean by unique??

Comment: distinct not taking the same value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximal order of an element in a symmetric group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221211/maximal-order-of-an-element-in-a-symmetric-group)

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee No need to, but since we're trying to maximize lcm, I think each number is likely to be distinct in the end.

Comment: @Peter Taylor Thanks, that is what I wanted! But also, do you have any idea for calculating the exact partition that lcm is maximized?

Comment: I have a definite memory of writing a program to calculate these numbers for some challenge site - probably Project Euler - but I can't remember enough to find the program on my hard disk. Nevertheless, I think it's probably easy to prove that the partition should be into prime powers (plus maybe a small useless remnant), and then a recursive search would be reasonably efficient.

Comment: @Peter Taylor Thanks for your help!! It was very helpful. I'll try proving the prime power property.