# Orders of Elements in Symmetric Groups

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, symmetric-groups

We define the symmetric group $S_n$ to be the set of all permutations of the first $n$ natural numbers. Moreover, we define the set $T_n$ as the set of all possible orders of elements in $S_n$ i.e.

$$T_n=\{ \space|\sigma| \mid \sigma \in S_n \}$$

We are interested in studying the set $T_n$.

---

First, we can start by observing when $x \in T_n$, given positive integers $x$ and $n$. Clearly, $x=1$ is an element of $T_n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ since the identity permutation has order $1$. For $x>1$, let the prime factorization of $x$ be:
$$x=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{a_i}$$
Assume that a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ has order $x$. Let the unique cycle decomposition (with cycles of length $1$ ignored) of $\sigma$ be:
$$\sigma=\prod_{j=1}^t C_j$$
We have $x=|\sigma|=\text{lcm}(|C_1|,|C_2|,\ldots,|C_t|)$. Using this equation, we can show that for every $1 \leqslant i \leqslant k$, there exists some $1 \leqslant j \leqslant t$ such that $p_i^{a_i} \mid |C_j|$. This implies that $p_i^{a_i} \leqslant |C_j|$. Moreover, if we have multiple prime powers, say $p_1^{a_1}, p_2^{a_2}, \ldots ,p_i^{a_i}$ (WLOG a list of $i$ prime powers) all dividing $|C_j|$, we can see that:
$$p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_i^{a_i} \mid |C_j| \implies p_1^{a_1}+p_2^{a_2}+\cdots+p_i^{a_i} < p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_i^{a_i} \leqslant |C_j|$$

This tells us that: 
$$\sum_{i=1}^k p_i^{a_i} \leqslant \sum_{j=1}^t |C_j| \leqslant n \implies \sum_{i=1}^k p_i^{a_i} \leqslant n$$

However, one can see that this is a sufficient condition for the existence of a permutation $\sigma$ as we can set $k=t$ and $|C_i|=p_i^{a_i}$ for all $1 \leqslant i \leqslant k$. Thus:
$$x \in T_n \iff \sum_{i=1}^k p_i^{a_i} \leqslant n$$

---

We can see that the sum of the prime powers in the factorization of numbers is relevant in studying $T_n$. Thus, we define:
$$f \bigg( \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{a_i} \bigg) = \sum_{i=1}^k p_i^{a_i}$$

One result we can deduce using this function is showing that the only exception to $|T_n|>|T_{n-1}|$ for $n>2$ is $n=6$. Clearly, we can see from above that:
$$|T_n|>|T_{n-1}| \iff \exists \space x \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } f(x)=n$$

We can check that $n=1,6$ are the only exceptions till $n<11$. For $n \geqslant 11$, we prove by induction hypothesis. We assume that $1$ and $6$ are the only exceptions until $n-1$. As $11$ is the second Ramanujam prime, we have:
$$\pi(n)-\pi \bigg(\frac{n}{2} \bigg) \geqslant 2$$

So, let two primes in the interval $\bigg(\frac{n}{2},n \bigg]$ be $p$ and $q$. Clearly, $n-p$ and $n-q$ are not simultaneously $1$ and $6$ due to parity. WLOG, let $n-p \neq 1,6$. We have:
$$f(x)=n-p \implies f(px)=n$$
Note that $p \nmid x$ as $p>n-p$. Thus, we have concluded that $|T_n|>|T_{n-1}|$ for $n>2, n\neq6$.

---

We can see that the observation of $f(x)$ gives us better insight on the set $T_n$. I have the following questions:

$1.$ What is the average order of $f(x)$? Can we write an asymptotic expression for the same?

$2.$ Is there an asymptotic expression for $|T_n|$? Can we say anything about the same using the function $f(x)$?

Comment: I suggest you use different notation than $A_n,$ since that is reserved in group theory for the alternating group acting on $n$ elements.

Comment: @Shaun Would $T_n$ be alright? What do you think good notation would be?

Comment: Yeah, $T_n$ would be fine.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks! Any ideas about the question?

Comment: You're welcome. Nothing leaps out at me as obvious on a first reading. I'm afraid I don't have the time to go into sufficient detail.

Comment: There are asymptotic formulae for the maximal element of $T_n$, using Landau's function. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221211/maximal-order-of-an-element-in-a-symmetric-group) for example.

Comment: The sequence $|T_n|$ is on OEIS. https://oeis.org/A009490

Answer (score 4):

Let us consider all of the primes $p_i$ that could appear in one of the orders $\mathcal{T}_n$ in order to approximate $T_n \overset{\text{def}}{=} |\mathcal{T}_n|$. It is straight forward to see that a necessary and sufficient condition for this to occur is that $\log_{p_i}(n)\geq 1$; more generally for prime power $p_i^k$ a necessary and sufficient condition is that $\log_{p_i^k}(n)\geq 1$. Let us denote this set of primes as 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{S}_n \overset{\text{def}}{=} \{ p_i \in \mathbb{P} \ | \ p_i\leq n \}.
\end{equation}
From the set $\mathcal {S}_n$ we can define a set of ***integer partitions*** that will give us the exact value of $T_n$; indeed if we let
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{P}_n \overset{\text{def}}{=} \left\{ y = \sum_{x \in S} x^{e_i} \ \Bigg| \ S \subset\mathcal{S}_n ,\ y \leq n , \ e_i \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}  \right\}
\end{equation} 
then we have the equality $T_n = P_n \overset{\text{def}}{=} |\mathcal{P}_n|$. The beautiful thing is that $P_n$ can be enumerated by taking the following generating function 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}_n (x) = \prod_{p \in \mathcal{S}_n}\left(1+\sum_{l \in \mathbb{N}}x^{p^l}\right)
\end{equation} 
and summing up the first $n$ coefficients $F_i$ 
[see sec.5.3 of Chen & Khee Meng for generating function techniques for partitions](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Principles_and_Techniques_in_Combinatori/gFo4LJmSe6gC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover). In other words if we let 
\begin{equation}
F_m = [x^m]\mathcal{F}_n (x) = [x^m] \prod_{p \in \mathcal{S}_n}\left(1+\sum_{l \in \mathbb{N}}x^{p^l}\right)
\end{equation} 
where $F_m = [x^m]\mathcal{F}_n (x) $ is defined by the relation 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}_n (x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}F_kx^k
\end{equation} 
then we have that 
\begin{equation}
T_n = P_n = \sum_{k \leq n}F_k.
\end{equation} 
While [Flajolet and Sedgewick](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf) contains a wealth of methods for asymptotic approximations (which you definitely should look into) we can already try to get a rough approximation that is computationally feasible.

For simplicity let 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{S}_n^{<\omega} \overset{\text{def}}{=} \{ p_i^l \leq n \ | \ p_i \in \mathcal{S}  \}.\end{equation}

We know that [asymptoticly we have the following approximation](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf) $p_k \sim k\log k $ and therefore (by Sterling's approximation) that if $k$ is the largest number satisfying $\log k! \leq n $ then it is approximately equal the largest prime smaller than $n$;  furthermore remembering the original constraint on the exponents we also have
\begin{equation}
\log^l k! \leq n \implies \log^l k! \in \mathcal{S}_n^{<\omega}
\end{equation} 
and also that 
 \begin{equation}
\log^l k! \leq n \implies l \leq \frac{\log n}{\log \log k!} 
\end{equation} 
 Therefore we can approximate $F_n $ as 
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}_n (x) = \prod_{p \in \mathcal{S}_n}\left(1+\sum_{l \in \mathbb{N}}x^{p^l}\right) \sim \prod_{\log k! \leq n}\left(1+\sum_{l \leq \frac{\log n}{\log \log k!} }x^{\log^l k!}\right).
\end{equation} 
Defining $F^*_m$ as follows
 \begin{equation}
F^*_m = [x^m] \mathcal{F}^{*}_n (x) = [x^m]\prod_{\log k! \leq n}\left(1+\sum_{l \leq \frac{\log n}{\log \log k!} }x^{ \log^l k!}\right),
\end{equation} 
***we can get a fast approximation*** for $T_n$ as
 \begin{equation}
T_n  \approx \sum_{i\leq n} F_i^*
\end{equation} 
and seeing as the equivalnce of the enumeration problem you asked for is essentially reduced to a difficult problem I doubt there will be a simple closed form solution (but you might be able to find better approximations).

Good luck on your mathematical adventures young padawan! Bon Voyage!

**Explicit derivation of the generating function** The user [Angela](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15624/angela-pretorius) has brought it my attention that there is another generating function $\mathcal{T}(x) = \frac{1}{1-z}\prod_{p : \text{ prime}}\left(1+\sum_{l \in \mathbb{N}}x^{p^l}\right)$ given in this link to the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A009490). This is in fact equivalent to the solution given here, lest us give a proof.

***(Proof):*** The first thing to notice is that the generating function
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{F}_n (x) = \prod_{p \in \mathcal{S}_n}\left(1+\sum_{l \in \mathbb{N}}x^{p^l}\right) = (1+x^2+x^4+...)(1+x^3+x^9+ ...) (1+x^5+...)...
\end{equation}
is the sequence counts the number of ways as representing any $k \leq n$ as a sum of distinct prime powers. To see the reason why just interepret  *multiplication* as an *and* and the *addition* as an *or* see ["On Picture-Writing" by Gearge Polya](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2309555?seq=1). So that for example $[x^5]\mathcal{F}_n(x)$ will be equal to $2$ because one can only choose $x^2$ and $x^3$ from the first two products or choose $x^5$ from the third product to get exponents that add up to the exponent $x^5$. The point of replacing $p : \text{ prime}$ with $p \in \mathcal{S}_n$ is that when you actually go to compute the generating function you can only perform a finite number of operations. The question post by [Haran](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/438557/haran) essentially contains a proof of the fact that $\sum_{k\leq n}F_k = T_n$. Therefore using the relation 
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{1-x}\mathcal{A}(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left(\sum_{k \leq n} a_k\right )x^n
\end{equation}
we get that 
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{T} (x) = \frac{1}{1-x}\prod_{p : \text{ prime}}\left(1+\sum_{l \in \mathbb{N}}x^{p^l}\right),
\end{equation}
but if we are only interested in the terms up until $n$ (which is what you are going to have to do in practice) you can just use 
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{T}_n (x) = \frac{1}{1-x}\prod_{p \in \mathcal{S}_n}\left(1+\sum_{l \in \mathbb{N}}x^{p^l}\right). 
\end{equation}
**QED**

Comment: How did you derive the generating function $$\mathcal{F}_n (x) = \prod_{p \in \mathcal{S}_n}\left(\sum_{l \in \mathbb{N}}x^{p^l}\right)=(x+x^2+x^4+...)(x+x^3+x^9+...)(x+x^5+x^25+...)$$? When I multiply out the brackets, all the $x^k$ coefficients turn out to be zero.

Comment: The OEIS page give the generating function for $|T_n|$ as $$\frac{1}{1-x}\prod_p\left(1+\sum_{k\geq 1}x^{p^k}\right)$$.

Comment: Hey, Angela thanks for proofreading! I have fixed the mistake with the zero exponents. It is not immediately clear to me why the factor of $\frac{1}{1-x}$. I will have to go to that link you posted and investigate further.

Comment: Hey Angela the point of the $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is to sum up the $F_n$. **Notice that I did not say that $F_n = T_n$ I said that $T_n = \sum_{k\leq n}F_k$.**

Comment: The $\frac{1}{1-z}$ is the partial sum operation on generating functions.   You can find a nice explanation here https://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/30gf/ on Sedgewick's website. Once again thanks for helping fix the mistake instead of just downvoting lol.

Comment: @PedroJuanSoto My question body contains the proof till $T_n=\sum_{k \leqslant n} F_k$. I think that you have made an error after defining $S^{< \omega}$. We needed $p_i^l \leqslant n$ which would show $p_i \leqslant n^{1/l}$. Then, for the largest prime $p_k$, we have the largest $k$ such that $(\log k!)^l \leqslant n$. You have mistaken this to be $\log (k!^l)=l\log{k!}$ while saying $$l \leqslant \frac{n}{\log{k!}}$$

Comment: Hey haran thanks for pointing out this typo. It has a simple fix, put a $\log$ in front of the $n$; i.e. $n/ \log (k!) \to  \log n/  \log (k!) $. Take care!

Comment: @PedroJuanSoto I still think this is wrong. I believe it should be $$l \leqslant \frac{\log{n}}{\log{\log{k!}}}$$

Comment: Lol, yea my bad. I fixed it. Hopefully no more errors! Thanks, take care!