# Maximum value of $\text{lcm}(n_1,n_2,...,n_k)$ given $n_1+...+n_k=X$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Find the maximum value of $\text{lcm}(n_1,n_2,...,n_k)$ given $n_1+...+n_k=X\in\mathbb{Z^+}$,where $n_1,...,n_k$ and $k$ are to be determined.

I came across this as a lemma while solving a group theory problem.

By AMGM, $$\frac{n_1+...+n_k}{k}\ge \sqrt{n_1...n_k}\\\iff \frac{X}{k}\ge\sqrt{\text{LCM$\times$ GCD}}\\\iff\text{LCM}\le\frac{X^2}{k^2\times{\text{GCD}}}$$

Now the LCM is obtained if and only if all the $n$ are equal, but this becomes tricky. If we choose this, then the LHS bound changes, so perhaps we could do better if we chose a better bound but didn't get equality. Although this AMGM result looks huge, I would not be surprised if it was useless.

I've seen a similar problem before which is "Find the maximum value of $n_1n_2...n_k$ such that $n_1+...+n_k=100$". This is solved by taking as many threes as we can, then the rest twos. If in our problem we chose only primes, then the two problems are the same, so following the same principle, perhaps it is best to choose primes in ascending order ($n_1=2,n_2=3,n_3=5...$) until we get as close to $X$ as we can, then whatever is left over doesn't matter because we used up the primes anyway(so it won't increase the lcm).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $n_1n_2\cdots n_k\ne GCD\cdot LCM$

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function

Comment: @IvanNeretin Nevermind then I guess

Comment: I think you want to find the maximal order of the elements of the $X$-th symmetric group. As far as I know, there is no realyy nice formula.

Comment: I'm voting to close (my own) question because I don't think there are going to be any on-topic answers. but it might be better than deleting in case anyone else accidently blows an hour trying to prove the riemann hypothesis!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximal order of an element in a symmetric group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221211/maximal-order-of-an-element-in-a-symmetric-group)