# How to find permutations with maximum cycle

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

This is probably a question that has been asked before and is addressed in a textbook, but I can't find the answer, so I'll ask anyways.

Let $P =\lbrace p_{0}, p_{1}, p_{2}, ... p_{n-1}\rbrace$ be an arbitrary permutation of the set $\lbrace0, 1, 2, ... n-1\rbrace$.  So the cardinality of $P$ is $n$ and the count of possible $P$ is $n!$.

Define a "self permuting" function $f: P \mapsto P'$ such that $f(p'_{i})=p_{p_{i}}$.  For example, $P= \lbrace3,2,0,1\rbrace, P' = \lbrace1,0,3,2\rbrace$ and $P''= \lbrace 0, 1, 2, 3 \rbrace$.  This function probably already has a name somewhere.  I just don't know what it is or how to find it.  I am trying to determine which $P$ cycles through all $n!$ permutations. There are obvious permutations where it doesn't such, as when a $p_{i}=i$ or a conjugate pair, $p_{i}=p_{j}, \;\; p_{j}= p_{i}$. Outside of brute force, which is computationally impractical for all but the smallest $n$, is there a method to do so?

Comment: For $n\ge3,$ no $P$ "cycles to all $n!$ permutations", because the [symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) is not a [cyclic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) (it is not even an [abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group)).

Comment: Thanks for providing the definition of symmetric group.

Comment: You will be interested by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/221211/305862)